# How to use map and grep in Perl for following data

Tags: perl, dictionary, grep

How to display only the chains (such as `A, C, E, G`) which end with a semicolon `;`

**Data**

```
COMPND    MOL_ID: 1;                                                            
COMPND   2 MOLECULE: JACALIN;                                                   
COMPND   3 CHAIN: A, C, E, G;                                                   
COMPND   4 SYNONYM: JACKFRUIT 
AGGLUTININ;                                       
COMPND   5 MOL_ID: 2;                                                           
COMPND   6 MOLECULE: JACALIN;                                                   
COMPND   7 CHAIN: B, D, F, H;                                                   
COMPND   8 SYNONYM: JACKFRUIT AGGLUTININ
```

I tried the below code

```
#!usr/local/bin/perl

open(FILE, "/home/httpd/cgi-bin/r/1JAC.pdb");

while ( $line = <FILE> ) {

    if ( $line =~ /^COMPND/ ) {

        #$line = substr $line,4,21;

        my $line =~ m(/\$:^\w+\$\;/g);
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `AGGLUTININ` really start on a new line?

Comment: `map` and `grep` are powerful tools, but ... if you don't follow what they're doing, don't use them. They're very much case studies in: "“Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?”" - Brian Kernighan

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -nle'print $1 if /^COMPND\s+\S*\s*CHAIN:(.+);/' /home/httpd/cgi-bin/r/1JAC.pdb
```

This is a fairly simple method of "grepping" part of a line to standard output. It will capture everything in the parentheses and print it.

- `-n` uses a `while(<>)` loop to read data from your file
- `-l` handles newlines

Comment: your script not give the result for this pdb file http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/4DX9.pdb

Comment: @Hussain That file does not follow the same structure as the one in the question. Lines are continued on the next line, and ended with `;` there. That is no longer trivial to parse, as you need multiline checking.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Hmm ya i need one liner for multiline checking. can you post it.?

Comment: @Hussain You need it? This is [real program](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5005858/real-program)'s question. It is not trivial to do, since you must exclude the beginning of the new line, and make sure you do not corrupt data. The best thing to do would be to look at CPAN and see if someone has already created a parser for this file format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single regular expression like the following:

```
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    if ($line =~ /^COMPND.+?CHAIN:\s*(.*?)\s*;\s*$/) {
        my $chain = $1;
        print "$chain\n";
    }
}
```

This uses a regular expression to match COMPND, CHAIN and an ending `;`. The `\s*` at the end of the regular expression will match any trailing spaces. It will capture the string between `CHAIN:` and `;` excluding trailing and leading spaces in `$1` which is set as the value for the `$chain` variable.

More information on [Perldoc: Perlre - Perl regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: The example has been updated to capture and output the chain value, e.g. "A, C, E, G".

Answer (score 0):

You may like this one-line solution

```
perl -le 'print for map /CHAIN:\s*([^;]+)/, <>' /home/httpd/cgi-bin/r/1JAC.pdb
```

**output**

```
A, C, E, G
B, D, F, H
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU grep with perl regular expressions: find the text between "CHAIN:" and the semicolon

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=CHAIN: ).*?(?=;)' filename
A, C, E, G
B, D, F, H
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
use warnings;
use strict;
open my $nis,"<1jac.pdb";
my @ar = grep{ m/^COMPND/g} <$nis>;
my $s = join("",@ar);
my @dav;
my @mp2  = map{split(/,\s|,/, $_)} grep{ s/(COMPND\s+\d+\s+(CHAIN\:\s+)?)|(\n|;)//g} @dav= $s =~m/(COMPND\s+\d+\s+CHAIN\:.+?(?:.|\n)+?\;)/g;
$, = ", ";
print @mp2;
```

Output

```
A, C, E, G, B, D, F, H
```